# How do I process email from timestamp with exchangelib?

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime, exchangelib

I will be storing the last processed email timestamp to the database and then when I run the process I want to do greater than that email timestamp.

Right now I m doing this way.. which was fine to run for old records but now I want to automate this with a corn job run every 1 hour.

```
pytz_tz = pytz.timezone('US/Pacific')
py_dt = pytz_tz.localize(datetime(2022, 2, 3))
py_dt1 = pytz_tz.localize(datetime(2022, 2, 4))  ####ENTER DATE
ews_bfr = EWSDateTime.from_datetime(py_dt)
ews_bfr1 = EWSDateTime.from_datetime(py_dt1)
# print(ews_bfr)


query = Q(subject='MediaCore process')
recent_emails = account.inbox.filter(~query, datetime_received__range=(
    ews_bfr,
    ews_bfr1
))
```

But now instead of using the start and end date, I want to pass the timestamp of the email to start from, Can anyone please advise or help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my result with the help of dateutil.parse

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

timestampdate = "2022-02-07 18:16:45+00:00"
recentkey = parse(timestampdate)

recent_emails = account.inbox.filter(datetime_received__gt = recentkey) ##__gt and gte for greater than or greater than or equal to for filtering.
```